# Blazor Entity framework no project found

Tags: c#, frameworks, blazor, entity

I try to create a database in my Blazor project but `No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.` is returned when I try to run `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` I have worked whit Entity framework before but never whit Blazor.
I am adding pictures of my project for reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Make sure that ur entering that command in the right directory. Find the location of ur folder, and use the `cd` command to navigate to it. For example `cd C:\Projects\Test\ `

Comment: Type `dir` into the console and press return. Show us the output

Comment: This is the output: https://prnt.sc/246kwha

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to do the Following Steps:

- Create the Blazor Project
- In Visual Studio go to SQL Server Object Explorer
- Add the Connection or Use an existing One
- Open Your Connection And Add a new Database on Databases Folder
- Right click on the Database Node and select Properties
- Copy the Connection String
- Paste it on the default Connection
- You have the database linked with your blazor project